# Docker delete all images script not working on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I need your help with a command I was using on Windows but on Ubuntu it won't work for me.

```bash
docker images | grep none | awk ' { print $3; } ' | xargs docker rmi -f & cls & docker images
```

With this command I get:

```bash
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}' as error.
cls is an alias I'm using and it's working`
```

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly do you want achieve?

Comment: maybe “system prune”  is better for that task

Comment: As an aside, you want to avoid the [useless `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: And “images prune”

Comment: I want to achive to delete all images with the tag <none>, but the docker images prune command never worked for me

Comment: and the command is now semi working after I replaced awk ' { print $3; } ' with awk " { print $3; } ", but somehow the output of the docker rmi commad is after all the clear & docker images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I got it working with:

```bash
docker images | grep none | awk " { print $3; } " | xargs docker rmi -f ; clear ; docker images
```

Thanks for your efforts tho, it helped me with other problems :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve is to delete all dangling images (images not currently used with  as both REPOSITORY and TAG). Then you want to `clear` the terminal and to get a new list of docker images.

If gets you right the following may be found useful by you:

```bash
sudo docker image prune -a -f && clear && sudo docker images
```

Comment: this deletes only the newer image and not the older one with the <none> tag

Comment: yes and no, I only want to remove images with a <none> tag but they are still referenced with a repo